# How to add exoplayer in facebook litho for android

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x, facebook-litho

I have seen news feed example using fb [litho](https://github.com/facebook/litho). There is no any example for video play using litho. We want a example like news feed with video play or can you please provide any example or suggestion to add exoplayer in litho.

Comment: Are you able to do that? Can you please share the code?

Comment: Were you able to create news feed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much difference from adding any other custom view to Litho. You'll need to create a `MountSpec` for `PlayerView` and then include that MountSpec as a Component.

More info about [MountSpecs](https://fblitho.com/docs/mount-specs).

And here is a good example of MountSpec implementation for a ProgressBar: [ProgressSpec](https://github.com/facebook/litho/blob/master/litho-widget/src/main/java/com/facebook/litho/widget/ProgressSpec.java)